# Remove both Leading and Trailing zeros from Date

Tags: python, pandas

I've a `df` Like this

```
   time_col

0   02:10:41
1   09:19:22
2   10:55:46
3   30:64:50
```

I want to remove both `trailing` and 'Leading` zeros.

My expected output should look like

```
    time_col      Time
0   02:10:41   2:10:41
1   09:19:22   9:19:22
2   10:55:46  10:55:46
3   30:64:50   30:64:5
```

Any suggestions would be appriciated

Comment: Are you sure you want to remove the trailing 0? Assuming you have times this would change the meaning

Comment: This not true data frame I've just created a dummy data Frame so that I can apply for similar solution

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, then `strip` is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove `Leading zeros` use `lstrip()`

```
df['Time'] = df['time_col'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.lstrip('0'))
```

#output

```
    time_col       Time
0   02:10:41    2:10:41
1   09:19:22    9:19:22
2   10:55:46   10:55:46
3   30:64:50   30:64:50
```

If you want to remove `Trailing zeros` use `rstrip()`

```
df['Time'] = df['time_col'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.rstrip('0'))
```

#output

```
0   02:10:41  02:10:41
1   09:19:22  09:19:22
2   10:55:46  10:55:46
3   30:64:50   30:64:5
```

Your case...If you want to remove both `Leading` and `trailing` use `strip()`

```
df['Time'] = df['time_col'].astype('str').apply(lambda x: x.strip('0'))
```

#output

```
    time_col      Time
0   02:10:41   2:10:41
1   09:19:22   9:19:22
2   10:55:46  10:55:46
3   30:64:50   30:64:5
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`str.strip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
df['time_col'] = df['time_col'].str.strip('0')
```

*NB. There are also `str.lstrip` and `str.rstrip` to limit to left/right stripping respectively.*

Output:

```
   time_col
0   2:10:41
1   9:19:22
2  10:55:46
3   30:64:5
```

Comment: True...Thats why I've added sol for `Leading` and `trailing`  separately